# Regex to allow everything except to start with a whitespace

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text input which should allow everything(Alpha, numeric, special characters) except starting with a whitespace. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `/^\s/` would match that.

Comment: Any reason you don't just trim the space?

Comment: are you using `ng-model` with your text `input`?

Comment: Yes I am using ng-model with the input. I do not have to trim the whitespace. A user can still enter a whitespace and that should be detected dirty, this should should trigger change in color of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you are currently using the `ng-pattern` directive. Turn `ng-trim` to false so that you can evaluate the untrimmed value of the `ng-model`. ngTrim documentation found at **[input[text]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)** directive.

Try using this regex: `/^[^\s]+/`, with the `ng-pattern` directive.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/oYvFNh1u1SOqR7ROhC2B?p=preview)**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-trim="false" ng-pattern="/^[^\s]+/">
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use this regex:

```
^\S+$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fW7oF8/1)**

Also you may try to check [trim() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) which would be a better choice in this case.

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of the string.

Comment: I tried using this regex, but it triggers when the second input character is passed. It should do so when the first input is detected as a whitespace.

Comment: @Maverick2007:- Are you trying to restrict the user from entering the whitespace?

Comment: No, user can enter whitespace, but the validation will change the color of the input to show the user he cannot start with a whitespace.

Comment: @Maverick2007:- You may try this regex then:- `/^\S+$/`

Comment: This one as well does not produce desired result. For Example "Hello World" should be fine but " Hello World" should be invalid.